# ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,1024,300,476] vs. shape[1] = [1,1024,76,120]

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
with slim.arg_scope(resnet_arg_scope(is_training=(is_training and not_freezed[2]))):
    C4, _ = resnet_v1.resnet_v1(C3,
                                blocks[2:3],
                                global_pool=False,
                                include_root_block=False,
                                scope=scope_name)
# add_heatmap(C4, name='Layer/C4')
# C4 = tf.Print(C4, [tf.shape(C4)], summarize=10, message='C4_shape')
feature_c2=slim.conv2d_transpose(C2,
                                 1024,
                                 [3,3],                                  
                                 stride=4,
                                 padding='SAME')

feature_c3=slim.conv2d_transpose(C3,
                                 1024,
                                 [3,3],
                                 stride=2,
                                 padding='SAME') 
feature_to_cropped=tf.concat([**strong text**feature_c2,feature_c3,C4],3)
feature_to_cropped=slim.conv2d(feature_to_cropped,1024,[3,3],1)
print(C4)
print(feature_to_cropped)
return feature_to_cropped
```

I want to concat the feature map and I checked the shape of feature_c2 and feature_c3 are[1,height,width,1024],c4 is [1,height,width,1024],I concat them and conv ,the result to return is [1,height,width,1024],but why it need channel in the dim 2?

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): ConcatOp : Dimensions
>   of inputs should match: shape[0] = [1,1024,300,476] vs. shape[1] =
>   [1,1024,76,120]
>            [[Node: concat = ConcatV2[N=3, T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Conv2d_transpose/Relu,
>   Conv2d_transpose_1/Relu,
>   resnet_v1_101_3/block3/unit_23/bottleneck_v1/Relu,
>   postprocess_RPN/ones/Const)]]
>            [[Node: postprocess_fastrcnn/GatherV2_20/_1405 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1,
>   tensor_name="edge_4116_postprocess_fastrcnn/GatherV2_20",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]